# How to find all URLs in a website source code

Tags: python

I am making a python program that would get a Yandex Reverse Image Search page and get its source code, and then with the source code I'd print all the URLs that Yandex could find in the web..

Basically: Yandex searches the image on the web and returns a URL on where the image has been found.

So, the problem is: I can only get the full line the URL is on, meaning that instead of me getting "https://www.google.com/" as output, I'd get `<a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank" class="Link Link_view_default">Google</a>`

My code is pretty simple:

```
r = requests.get('https://yandex.com/images/search?rpt=imageview&lr=110480&url=https%3A%2F%2Favatars.mds.yandex.net%2Fget-images-cbir%2F1571103%2FdFrVvX1v9-W-uedRDwo0gQ3711%2Forig&cbir_id=1571103%2FdFrVvX1v9-W-uedRDwo0gQ3711', headers=headers)

print(r.text)
```

Is there anyway that I could print just google.com instead of that full line of HTML source?

Comment: A regex should do it: `re.findall(r'href="(.*?)"',my_string)`

Answer (score 2):

There are ways to get there, but the simplest one is using regex:

```py
import re

import requests

r = requests.get(
    'https://yandex.com/images/search?rpt=imageview&lr=110480&url=https%3A%2F%2Favatars.mds.yandex.net%2Fget-images-cbir%2F1571103%2FdFrVvX1v9-W-uedRDwo0gQ3711%2Forig&cbir_id=1571103%2FdFrVvX1v9-W-uedRDwo0gQ3711'
)

print(re.findall(r'href="(.*?)"', r.text))
```

This regex will find out all string slices that looks like `href="..."` (`.*?` will match any substring, and `()` means return this matched part as the result)

On the other hand, you can also try html parsers, like beautifulsoup.